# Why manjaro is so popular?

Tags: manjaro

Manjaro is a recent distribution very popular on distrowatch.
But how and why this distribution is so popular ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DistroWatch Page Hit Ranking statistics are a light-hearted way of measuring the popularity of Linux distributions and other free operating systems among the visitors of this website. They correlate neither to usage nor to quality and should not be used to measure the market share of distributions. They simply show the number of times a distribution page on DistroWatch.com was accessed each day, nothing more. — https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=popularity

Comment: Is there a better comparation with the numbers of users for each distribution ?